# Check if session value contains string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a condition based on a session value:

```
if session("legal_entity")="entity1" then
```

now, this works well,  but only if the value in `"session("legal_entity")"` is `"entity1"`.

how do I do if the value of `session("legal_entity")` is `"someText.entity1.someOtherText"`.

this would be to check for the `sub string`. I tried the following:

```
if session("legal_entity").Contains("entity1") then
```

but of course doesn't work.  What solution could I use to simply ask for the sub string inside the `session` value?

Comment: What do you mean by `but of course doesn't work` ? Are you getting any error? The value you are storing in session is a string value?

Comment: well, that it doesn't work,hence me asking for help.
I don;t have access to the solution, so I'm just editing the files with notepad, so I don't have debugger. yes, the value stored is a string

Comment: You code looks ok. You might want to log the value of session and value of `session("legal_entity").Contains("entity1")` in log file and see what exact values you are getting. You can also try using IndexOf function of String to check if entity1 exists in session value or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do that after converting to `string` like this

```
 if(Convert.ToString(Session["legal_entity"]) == "entity1")
```

or you can also cast the `(session) object` reference to `string`:

```
 if (((string)Session["legal_entity"]) == "entity1")
```

or if you want to use `contains` method than do that like this

```
if (Convert.ToString(Session["legal_entity"]).Contains("entity1"))
    {
       //your code here
    }
```

Comment: what can I do to compare with a string with wildcards? 
like = "entity%1" would work?  if let's say the value of legal_entity was "entity_Number_1"